# How to inject EntityManager in test directory?

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

This is my spring config based on hibernate. My problem is when I want to inject EntityManager in my test class. The problem is I get an exception that this.entitymanager is null and I don't know what to do with it. Does anybody have some idea what to do?

JpaConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createEMF(JpaVendorAdapter adapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "root");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "ErykSkoczylas1");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "drop-and-create");
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("shop-database");
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.database.models");
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter createVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class CustomerServiceTest {
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringJpaApplication.class);
    private CustomerService customerService = ctx.getBean(CustomerService.class);

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void method_addCustomerToDatabase_desc_CustomerServiceShouldAddCustomerToDatabaseAndShouldAddAddress() {
        Address address1 = new Address("Poland", "30-091", "Cracow", "street", 1);

        Customer customer = new Customer("John", "Smith", "xyz@test.com", new Date(11111999L), "password", false, address1);

        customerService.addCustomerToDatabase(customer);

        List<Customer> customers = findCustomers(customer);
        List<Address> addresses = findAddresses(address1);
        Address address2 = entityManager.find(Address.class, address1.getId());

        deleteCustomerFromDatabase(customers.get(0).getId());
        deleteAddressFromDatabase(addresses.get(0).getId());

        assertEquals(1, addresses.size());
        assertEquals(1, customers.size());
        assertEquals(1, address2.getCustomers().size());
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.getTransaction()" because "this.entityManager" is null
```

Comment: If you run your tests based on a test database then you should be able to achieve that. Otherwise best case scenario you mock that entityManager. Don't see any other alternative

Comment: You need to annotate the test class with the [Spring JUnit Runner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html), otherwise it's just a normal test. You need Spring to tap into the testing framework. You do this by using the runner. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith) for example. And you inject the EntityManager not the EMFactory